# How to find expected angle between two randomly generated vectors?

Tags: probability, geometry, probability-theory

Let us say two random points have been generated in a d-dimensional space by uniformly sampling from a unit cube centered at origin. How to calculate the expected angle between them?

Comment: What probability distribution are you using?

Comment: You must mean vectors, right? Just two points don't define an angle.

Comment: uniform distribution with in bounds@DanielRust

Comment: What's the shape of you bound? it matters.

Comment: yup i mean vectors@nayrb

Comment: hypercube of unit length@DanielRust

Comment: Let's say you have two points $x=(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$ and $y=(y_1, y_2, ..., y_n)$ Since your point are uniformly distributed in a unit cube, each of its coordinates is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. Expected cosine of the angle between them is the expected dot product of normalized $x$ and $y$: $E{[\cos{\alpha}]} = E[(x_1 \cdot y_1 + ... + x_n \cdot y_n)/\sqrt{(x_1^2 + ... + x_n^2)(y_1^2 + ... + y_n^2)}]$. I am not sure how to integrate it

Comment: Simulation seems to indicate that it's $90$ degrees (for all $d$). Is there some symmetry-way to see this?

Comment: I think the integral in @Valentine 's comment is symmetrical w.r.t for example the last $y_n$. The parts $[-0.5,0]$ and $[0,0.5]$ cancel each other, so it's $0$ and hence the angle a straigth angle. I'm I correct?

Comment: You don't really need uniform distribution. As long as your distribution is invariant under reflection $\vec{x} \to -\vec{x}$ and the probability that a zero vector is picked is $0$,  the expected angle is $\frac{\pi}{2}$. This is because for any pair of vectors $\vec{x},\vec{y}$, the outcome $(\vec{x}, \vec{y})$ and $(\vec{x},-\vec{y})$ is equally likely. If one of them is making an angle $\theta$, the other one is making an angle $\pi - \theta$.

Comment: @helloworld: Is the cube centered at the origin, or is the origin a corner, or something else?

Comment: origin is at the center @user86418

Comment: If the constraint of sampling from hyper-cube is relaxed, what could be the case?

Comment: @achillehui: Post as an answer...? :)

Comment: @helloworld: Thank you for clarifying. :) Regarding relaxing the conditions, you have to be Very Specific, and should start a new question containing the necessary details. (It would also be appropriate to edit this question to make clear that you're sampling from the unit cube $[-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]^{n}$ with the uniform distribution. Asking about "at random" without specifying your probability space _in detail_ is asking for trouble.)

Answer (score 2):

The expected angle between two randomly generated vectors in an n-dimensional space ($n>1$) is 90 degrees. $P(x.y=a)=P(x.y=-a)$ since $P(y)=P(-y)$ since $y$ is a random vector.  Thus $P(cos(\theta) = b) = P(cos(\theta) = -b)$ and $P(\theta = 90+c) = P(\theta+ 90-c)$.  Thus

$\int_{0}^{180}  \theta P(\theta) d \theta = \int_{0}^{180} (\theta-90) P(\theta) d \theta + 90 \int_{0}^{180} P(\theta) d \theta = 0 + 90 \times 1 = 90$

where the first integral vanishes because

$\int_{0}^{180} (\theta-90) P(\theta) d \theta = \int_{0}^{90} (\theta-90) P(\theta) d \theta + \int_{90}^{180} (\theta-90) P(\theta) d \theta = 0$

the two integrals take opposite values due to symmetry.  Note that 
$\int_{0}^{180} P(\theta) d \theta =1$.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix one of the vectors to be (for example) on the $x_1$-axis. Let's call the other vector $y = (y_1, y_2, \dots, y_d)$.

Let's calculate the expexted value of the inner product of the two vectors (since this defines the angle, the normalization doesn't really matter). Since we fixed the other vector to be $(1,0,0\dots, 0)$, it becomes just

$$\int_{-a}^a y_1 \space dy_1= 0$$

The expected angle is $\arccos 0 = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: The cosine of the expected angle is not the same as the expected cosine of the angle. I do think the expected angle should still turn out to be $\pi/2$, but this argument does not show it.

Comment: I see. There should be $\arccos$ inside the integral. And the division by the norm of $y$. Since these are also symmetrical (on the sides $y_1 < 1$ and $y_1>1$). It's two times this value. Upon calculation it must be $\frac{1}{2}(\arccos - 0)$.

Comment: since one of the vector is being fixed on one of its axis,it always turns out to be  π/2 irrespective of other. My doubt here is that both the vectors are randomly generated. Does the intuition of fixing one vector is valid?

Comment: @helloworld It's not always $\pi/2$ if one is fixed. You can rotate the two vectors s.t one lands on the axis (and the angle is preserved). But, as noticed, my argument is somewhat faulty. (I'm not totally sure of whether we can fix the other vector either.)